# Can you put a client into a widget hierarchy in awesome-wm?

Tags: awesome-wm

I was wondering if you can put the client into a widget hierarchy.
Basically is there a way to do something like:

```lua
local cool_background_widget = wibox.widget({
    widget = wibox.container.background,
    {
        client, --??????
    }
})
```

I'm expecting there isn't but if there's not, is there some hacky way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no. But there's a few way around this.

#### 1: Using a client + titlebars as top bar

If you only need a single client within your wibar/wibox, then you can put a different titlebar around that client and use that as your top (or whatever) bar. To add space like a normal bar, either play with the client `:struts()` property or use `screen.padding`.

#### 2: Create a custom placeholder widget

The second option is to create a new widget, then use its own `:draw()` function as a hook to know when to move the client (using `c:geometry()`). This is mostly what [the dynamic client layout branch does](https://github.com/Elv13/awesome-1/blob/doc_tests_and_notif/lib/dynamite/widget/placeholder.lua). This has some issues like having to keep raising the client. You also have to disconnect a bunch of thing to prevent existing code path from affecting client (like the `request::geometry` handlers, such as the one to move/resize the client using `mod4+mouse`). You also need to make the client `floating` and `sticky` to get the correct result.

#### 3: Patches welcome

It is important to keep in mind that there is no technical limitations that prevent this feature from being implemented. There is an existing [issue](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/issues/650) regarding adding this. In some alternate universe where both the core AwesomeWM developers would have unlimited time, this would be a feature. We are discussing doing it for the individual systray "icons" first. This [issue](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/issues/2637#issuecomment-460931823) is also a good reference, but in this case would not be enough to implement what you request.